# Other values for the __name__variable in python

Tags: python, variables, branch

From what I understand, the following statement is used to make the program only run a branch if the program is run standalone.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

What are other values the `__name__` variable can assume, and what are its uses?

Answer (score 0):

The `if __name__ == "__main__"`: ... trick exists in Python so that our
 Python files can act as either reusable modules, or as standalone programs.
 When our scripts are used as standalone programs than `__name __` is `__main__`

But When we run our script from some other module the variable `__name__` assumes name of its module, so we know from that the script is being imported and not called from interactive prompt.
For ex make a script `test.py` with a simple stamtement in it:

```
print __name__
```

Now now from `cmd` when you do :

```
>>>python test.py
>>>__main__     #you get this output
```

Now let us assume you are import this in some other module (say `test2.py`) and its contents are:

```
print "running test2"
import test
```

Then you would get this output:

```
running test2
test
```

Comment: It worked almost exactly as you said, but the output was 
`running test2
test` 
instead of `test 2`

Comment: Thanks for specifying :) just tested it and modified the answer :)